# javascript string: remove all except numbers and the first "."

Tags: javascript, string

For example:

"10.0.cm" goes to "10.0"

and

"10.0.m" goes to "10.0"

and

"3" stays as "3"

etc...

I tried this:

```
values[3].replace(/[^0-9.,]+/, '')
```

but this still leaves the "." after the number, eg: 10.0.

Thanks for your help...

Comment: This worked...
value.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/)[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex should solve it

```
values[3].replace(/\.+[a-z]*$/, '')
```

Comment: thanks, that leaves me with the bit that I don't want though : 
"10.0.cm".replace(/[0-9]+\.*[0-9]*/, '') - ".cm"
how do swap that around?

Answer (score 2):

```js
var values = ["10.0.cm", "10.0.m", "3"];
var patten = /\d+(\.\d+)?/g;
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    console.info(values[i].match(patten));
}
```

Comment: This will return a length `2` _Array_ which contains two `.`s if given a _String_ like `'foo_1.0.bar.1.2.xyz'`

Answer (score 1):

The problem you've described isn't a simple "find numbers in a *String*"

It's not easy to do this in one step because *RegExp* in *JavaScript* doesn't support lookbacks. However

- It's pretty easy to remove all characters which aren't a digit or `.`
- It's pretty easy to find specific chars in a *String*
- It's pretty easy to build a *String*

```
var str = 'foo_1.0.bar.1.2.xyz';

str = str.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '').split('.');
str = str[0] ? str[0] + '.' + str.slice(1).join('') : '';

str; // "1.012"
```